# MJML Column Gutter and Column Division

Tags: html, css, web, mjml

[I Want To Build Thin In MJML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m98T7.png)

Can Some One Give Me The Code For This Using MJML I Cant Seem To Get It Right Thank You.

This Part Is a Must

```
  <mj-column background-color="#f6f6f6">
    <mj-text padding="20px" container-background-color="#4f4f4f" color="#f6f6f6" text-decoration>Connect With US</mj-text>
    <mj-image src="social-media-icon-5.png" href="https://example.com/social-media-5" />
    <mj-image src="social-media-icon-6.png" href="https://example.com/social-media-6" />
    <mj-image src="social-media-icon-5.png" href="https://example.com/social-media-5" />
    <mj-image src="social-media-icon-6.png" href="https://example.com/social-media-6" />
    </mj-cpolumn>
  </mj-column>
</mj-section>
```

My Code